# Unable to publish "ERROR AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - Unable to connect to remote address"

Tags: publishing, publishingfailed

The status is stuck at "Waiting for Publish".

Error in log:

> ERROR AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - Unable to connect to remote address

Note: Telnet to the presentation server is working fine.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion StackExchange, Please edit your question and provide a bit more detail what is the version of the Tridion, Looks like The Publish Transaction is waiting to be processed. Double check your publisher service/transport service and deployer services are running fine and check deployer service URL is accessible inside the CMS box. and Restart the Publisher service to check, check the cms logs and update the question.